# struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 288 bytes when unpacking c++ structure

Tags: python, c++, sockets, struct

First of all I'm sorry if this question has already been asked and answered but I thought my situation is different to the other answers I have been trying to find. Also I am very new to c++.

I am basically wanting to create a system where a c++ program receives data from a game and sends it over a socket to a python script. This data is stored in C++ as a structure and is being sent as a structure. I am currently stuck on receiving the data in python and actually putting it in a readable format.

Code is here:

Structure:

```
struct SPageFilePhysics
{

    int packetId = 0;
    float gas = 0;
    float brake = 0;
    float fuel = 0;
    int gear = 0;
    int rpms = 0;
    float steerAngle = 0;
    float speedKmh = 0;
    float velocity[3];
    float accG[3];
    float wheelSlip[4];
    float wheelLoad[4];
    float wheelsPressure[4];
    float wheelAngularSpeed[4];
    float tyreWear[4];
    float tyreDirtyLevel[4];
    float tyreCoreTemperature[4];
    float camberRAD[4];
    float suspensionTravel[4];
    float drs = 0;
    float tc = 0;
    float heading = 0;
    float pitch = 0;
    float roll = 0;
    float cgHeight;
    float carDamage[5];
    int numberOfTyresOut = 0;
    int pitLimiterOn = 0;
    float abs = 0;
    float kersCharge = 0;
    float kersInput = 0;
    int autoShifterOn = 0;
    float rideHeight[2];
    float turboBoost = 0;
    float ballast = 0;
    float airDensity = 0;
    float airTemp = 0;
    float roadTemp = 0;
    float localAngularVel[3];
    float finalFF = 0;
    float performanceMeter = 0;

    int engineBrake = 0;
    int ersRecoveryLevel = 0;
    int ersPowerLevel = 0;
    int ersHeatCharging = 0;
    int ersIsCharging = 0;
    float kersCurrentKJ = 0;

    int drsAvailable = 0;
    int drsEnabled = 0;

    float brakeTemp[4];
    float clutch = 0;

    float tyreTempI[4];
    float tyreTempM[4];
    float tyreTempO[4];

    int isAIControlled;

    float tyreContactPoint[4][3];
    float tyreContactNormal[4][3];
    float tyreContactHeading[4][3];

    float brakeBias = 0;

    float localVelocity[3];

    int P2PActivations = 0;
    int P2PStatus = 0;

    int currentMaxRpm = 0;

    float mz[4];
    float fx[4];
    float fy[4];
    float slipRatio[4];
    float slipAngle[4];


    int tcinAction = 0;
    int absInAction = 0;
    float suspensionDamage[4];
    float tyreTemp[4];

};
```

Sending data to python:

```
SPageFilePhysics* pfp = (SPageFilePhysics*)m_physics.mapFileBuffer;

send(connection, (char*)&pfp, sizeof(pfp), 0);
```

Receiving data (Python):

```
import socket, struct

#Variables
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
physicsFormat = 'ifffiiffffffffffffffffffffiifffifffffffffiiiiifiifffffifffffiiifffffiiff'


socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 42579))

print("--------------DATA--------------")

data = socket.recv(4096)
print(data)
print(struct.unpack(physicsFormat, data))
```

Python Output:

```
--------------DATA--------------
b'\x00\x00\xb0/\x9c\x02\x00\x00'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/lolamnma/Desktop/Telemtry Projects/OSIRIS_Telemetry/connect.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(struct.unpack(physicsFormat, data))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 288 bytes
```

My confusion here is shouldn't the data that is being printed out be more than that? If so is it because it isn't receiving data from the game and all of the values inside the structure are 0. Also why am I getting the buffer error. Sorry I don't normally ask questions on sites but I just can't seem to find the answer. Any help will be immensely appreciated <3.

EDIT:
Apologies for not showing all of the code. A brief example of what it does..

```
void initPhysics()
{
    TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Local\\acpmf_physics");
    m_physics.hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics), szName);
    if (!m_physics.hMapFile)
    {
        MessageBoxA(GetActiveWindow(), "CreateFileMapping failed", "ACCS", MB_OK);
    }
    m_physics.mapFileBuffer = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(m_physics.hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics));
    if (!m_physics.mapFileBuffer)
    {
        MessageBoxA(GetActiveWindow(), "MapViewOfFile failed", "ACCS", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what this function does to be honest.

```
m_physics.hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics), szName);
```

I am assuming the above part allows me to see what the data, which is stored in memory, from the game I want to extract data from

after calling this function my code then creates a socket (I'm not including this bit since I don't think you need to see it. It is a server so it accepts a connection with my python script and just sends the data over with:

```
send(connection, (char*)&pfp, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics), 0);
```

```
SPageFilePhysics* pfp = (SPageFilePhysics*)m_physics.mapFileBuffer;
```

This gets the data but again i'm not quite sure what this does as well. All I know is that it populates the structure with the game data.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, most forced type conversions are a sign of bad code and possible bugs, so try to avoid them. Make sure you at least understand why you make them! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hello, thank you for the useful information and I'm sorry for making you wait longer when you are being so kind as to help me. I have updated the question above which hopefully gives all the information that you need.

Comment: ***BEWARE*** that `socket.recv` returns all the available data... which means that it might only receive half the data because the rest hasn't been sent yet! You need to call it in a loop until you have at least 288 bytes. And then you might have *more* than 288 bytes if you got some of the *next* structure as well.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. How would you go about receiving the data. I'm stuck trying to sort it out. @user253751

Comment: @lolamnma something like (not python syntax): `/* only the first time */ received_data = b""; /* every time */ while(len(received_data) < 288) {received_data += socket.recv(4096);} process data;`

Comment: @user253751 thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in:

```
send(connection, (char*)&pfp, sizeof(pfp), 0);
```

You are calculating the pointer size instead of data size. And you are sending the pointer value.
Replace it with:

```
send(connection, pfp, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics), 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help changing the sizeof worked but changing it to pfp instead of  (char*)&pfp gives me 'argument of type SPageFilePhysics is incompatible with parameter of type const char *'.

Comment: pfp is SPageFilePhysics or SPageFilePhysics*?

Comment: SPageFilePhysics* .. Sorry the one thing I struggle with the most in c++ is understanding pointers and references. I get so confused with them.

Comment: Please see my comment concerning your question above. Your type conversions are broken and probably the cause of this and other issues, but it's hard to tell without a full picture.

Comment: try: send(connection, (void*)pfp, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics), 0)

Comment: Still producing argument of type void* is incompatible with parameter of type const char *.

Comment: what is the signature of send? Is it https://linux.die.net/man/2/send?

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I forgot to include that information above. I am using winsock2 since I'm working with windows applications.

Comment: just ask "please" :D send(connection, (const char*)(void*)pfp, sizeof(SPageFilePhysics), 0)